# Access Django DB objects without shell?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a request - can you help me access and manage django DB objects without using shell ?
I have created my models, but now (for example) i want to make a login system. I store users and passes(again, only an example), and i want to get the info from the DB, but i dont want to use shell.
What can i do in this case, im quite new to Django ?!
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Why not use django-admin?
Maybe this is what you want:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/

Answer (score 0):

In views.py you can import

from .models import modelname

data = modelname.objects.all() - using this you can get all the data from the Database
Eg:-
for d in data:
           print (d.email)
Will give all emails in the database

You can also use
t = modelname.objects.get(email='name@lk.com')
By this you can get the data of the person who's email is name@lk.com

Comment: i used this but it returned an error, the Class has no objects members - thats the error

Answer (score 0):

Django already has database support where you can register your models and access them with a graphical interface.

See the documentation: [django-admin-site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/)

First you need to create a super user account, if you don't have one, create it with the terminal in the project directory, use this row:

`python manage.py createsuperuser`

For your model to appear on the admin site you need to register it

```
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model)
    field1 = models.CharField()
    field2 = models.TextField()
    # ...

# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel

admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

So it's the basic way to register your model, if you want to personalize you need to check the documentation [ModelAdmin.fieldsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets)

with this done, just access the admin site at the link http://localhost:8000/admin/ and log in with the super user account and you will see the model registered.

Comment: ok i get this, but what if i need to access some other type of info. Or need to use in in a function(outside tje graphic inteface)

Comment: @StanislavIvanov You can access it by importing your model in your script
It would be like
```from myapp.models import MyModelName```
Accessing all the objects in it
```MyModelName.objects.all () ```